# How to use multiple models in one ListView Class on Django

Tags: python, django, class, listview

I want to create pege which previews auhors profile and posts with Django.

I created UserPostListView Class, then I want to search on Profile model by author's name and get profile.

How can I do this?

[All code here](https://github.com/igor-bond16/django_blog/tree/main/julia_blog)

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        output_size = (300,300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py(UserPostListView Class)

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserPostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profiles'] = Profile.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want the author profile of the posts which are in your post **queryset** that is a single user, so in your `get_context_data` you can get author for each post.

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["profile"] = Profile.objects.filter(user__username=self.kwargs.get("username"))
        return context
```